# Warning: Disabled/Deleted fields on Smart Groups

Tags: error, groups, errorhandling

After upgrading to CiviCRM 5.27 (and now, to 5.28) on Drupal 7, I see this warning message.

As you can see, GROUP is listed as "-" (minus).

[image]

When I try to click on settings (Gear icon), it shows me Group Settings empty fields:

[image]

When I click on *Contacts in this Group* (in Group Settings), it shows me all contacts in my CiviCRM database along with some notice warning (a lot of lines exactly like these - Undefined property and Undefined Index):

[image]

## UPDATE

(January, 2021)
The problem is still there after update to 5.33.2. What can I do about that?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with a couple ancient 'hidden smart groups.'  I'd be happy to delete them (and a boatload of other hidden smart groups associated with long-ago mailings that have been deleted), but I can't find any good way to do so.  I wonder if it possible to view and delete old hidden smart groups from within CiviCRM?

Comment: On a development server I deleted all hidden smart groups from the civicrm_group table, and all associated entries from civicrm_group_contact. I still see the error message, except the error message no longer lists two hidden smart groups. Instead there is just one line in the list - a dash where the  hidden field name should be, with edit and settings links for a the second of the two hidden groups originally flagged with errors (which no longer exist).  

Seems like CiviCRM has cached the original error - is there someway to clear that or will it eventually clear itself?

Answer (score 1):

To clear them click the left of the 2 small icons, then click the smart group criteria to go into search, hit the search button and create the smart group & then delete the smart group. Then it should disappear the warning message

Comment: Pradeep Nayak, I did as you recommended, but the warning is still there in CiviCRM System Status.

Comment: @Aivars You may have to repeat the create & deleting process many times until the message vanishes  I had to do it at least 7 times and every time the search criteria was different because more than one smart group cache may be causing this.

Comment: Thanks, @Tapash! Did it for 13 times, nothing seems to change. Actually, in my case the SEARCH CRITERIA are EMPTY, i.e. all contacts are included in this search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this query will help identify those orphaned saved searches that no longer have a group

```
select * from civicrm_saved_search where id not in (select saved_search_id from civicrm_group where saved_search_id is not null)
```